# Possible to control positioning in Android precisely using XML

Tags: android

I wanted to know if it was possible to precisely position widgets on Android using XML files? From my experiments, precise position seems impossible via XML. Programmatically, I'm able to position things perfectly based on the device width and height. However, using XML and dip values, things seem to fall apart. Here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088072/android-positioning-problems) of what I mean.

Mark Murphy, on an article, wrote:

> Some developers, perhaps those coming from the "drag-and-drop" school
>   of UI development, think first and foremost about the positions of
>   widgets. They think that they want certain widgets to be certain fixed
>   sizes at certain fixed locations. They get frustrated with Android
>   layout manager (containers) and may gravitate to the deprecated
>   AbsoluteLayout as a way to design UIs they way they used to.
>
> That rarely works well even on desktops, as can be seen by
>   applications that do not handle window resizing very well. Similarly,
>   it will not work on mobile devices, particularly Android, with its
>   range of screen sizes and resolutions.
>
> Instead of thinking about positions, think about rules. You need to
>   teach Android the "business rules" about where widgets should be sized
>   and placed, with Android then interpreting those rules based upon what
>   the device's screen actually supports in terms of resolution.

[source](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/18/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-2/)

This leads me to believe that precise positioning is difficult with XML files. This is important for my app because I'm laying out widgets on a background image so that these widgets need to be placed exactly on a particular area so that the overall UI looks good. The aspect ratio needs to be preserved across resolutions. Can I do all this using XML files?

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Positioning to line up with a background is really not recommended. The background image will adjust to the different screen sizes and then how would you know to adjust the widgets? Its basically a don't do it scenario.

Comment: thanks hannahmitt. but what about preserving the aspect ratio of the bg image? what if i have a image which looks good only with a 2:3 ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to pixel by pixel position your views using an [absolute layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html).
Last time I checked, which was a while ago, those drag and drop interfaces actually created one for you. (Actually just checking for the link seems that this class has been deprecated.)

However, I highly advise against using them. The reason is because you are coding for so many different screen sizes that providing pixel by pixel dimensions will certainly cause problems across devices.

What I would recommend is using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). I actually use this type of layout for everything that I can. It lets you put your items to right of, or above and below other elements. This combined with padding and margin options in DIP (density independent pixels) should let you create anything that you want. And it should look nice on most devices.

Comment: thanks frank. i did try positioning on relativelayout but couldnt control the widget positions precisely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088072/android-positioning-problems